# Simplify an integral involving trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

We were doing variation of parameters in differential equations tonight and had to do the following integral, the result given by hand calculations.

$$\int \cos t\tan^2 t\,dt=\ln|\sec t+\tan t|-\sin t$$

The students then tried the following in *Mathematica*:

```
v2 = Integrate[Cos[t] Tan[t]^2, t]
```

and got the following result:

```
-Log[Cos[t/2] - Sin[t/2]] + Log[Cos[t/2] + Sin[t/2]] - Sin[t]
```

I was able to come home and send them [some hand calculated](http://mse.redwoods.edu/darnold/math55/spring2015/Assignments/assignment16.nb) steps to equate this to our solution (minus the absolute value), but I was unable to show them equivalency using *Mathematica*.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `v1 = Cos[t] Tan[t]^2; Integrate[v1, t]; D[v2, t] == v1 // Simplify`

Comment: What is "our solution"?

Answer (score 3):

The result is a neat trick relying on D[Sec[x]+Tan[x],x]=Sec[x]^2+Sec[x]Tan[x]

(1) Transform Tan-squared to 1-Sec[x]^2

(2) Expand

(3) Integrate Cos[t]-Sec[t]

First is simple and the second Sec[t] can be done using the trick

Multiply by (Sec[x]+Tan[x])/(Sec[x]+Tan[x])

(4) You'll see the substitution u=Sec[x]+Tan[x] and the form Integrate[du/u,u]

Mathematica gets the half angle formula by representing Sec[x]+Tan[x] in terms of Sin[x/2] and Cos[x/2].

Comment: Sorry just read your notebook. You are well aware of the trick - just how do we get Mathematica to do the same?!

Comment: Using `TrigFactor[]` on `Sec[x]+Tan[x]` and `(Cos[x/2]+Sin[x/2])/(Cos[x/2]-Sin[x/2])` gives equivalency.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at Mathematica result $-\log\left(  \cos\frac{t}{2}-\sin\frac{t}
{2}\right)  +\log\left(  \cos\frac{t}{2}+\sin\frac{t}{2}\right)  $ and using
$\log\left(  \frac{x}{y}\right)  =\log x-\log y$ then Mathematica result can be written as

$$
\log\left(  \frac{\cos\frac{t}{2}+\sin\frac{t}{2}}{\cos\frac{t}{2}-\sin
\frac{t}{2}}\right)  =\log\left(  \frac{1+\tan\frac{t}{2}}{1-\tan\frac{t}{2}
}\right)
$$

Using $\tan\frac{t}{2}=\frac{\sin t}{1+\cos t}$ then above becomes

\begin{align*}
\log\left(  \frac{1+\frac{\sin t}{1+\cos t}}{1-\frac{\sin t}{1+\cos t}%
}\right)    & =\log\left(  \frac{1+\cos t+\sin t}{1+\cos t-\sin t}\right)
=\log\left(  \frac{1+\sin t}{\cos t}\right)  \\
& =\log\left(  \frac{1}{\cos t}+\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\right)  =\log\left(
\sec t+\tan t\right)
\end{align*}

Which is what the book gives. 
But interestingly, [Rubi 4.7](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/) gives different answer to this integral.

```
Clear[t];
mmaResult = Integrate[Cos[t] Tan[t]^2, t];
rubiResult = Int[Cos[t] Tan[t]^2, t];
Grid[{{Plot[mmaResult, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLabel -> Column[{"Mathematica", mmaResult}]],
  Plot[rubiResult, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> 
  Column[{"Rubi", rubiResult}]]
   }}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Rubi gives  `ArcTanh[Sin[t]] - Sin[t]` It is left as an exercise to the reader to determine which is the correct answer.

Comment: Interesting. The commands Plot[-Sin[t] + Log[Sec[t] + Tan[t]], {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All] and our hand calculated answer Plot[-Sin[t] + Log[Abs[Sec[t] + Tan[t]]], {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All] give the same plots. Which is understandable because Reduce[Sec[t] + Tan[t] > 0, t \[Element] Reals] // Simplify gives C[1] \[Element] Integers && -(\[Pi]/2) < t - 2 \[Pi] C[1] < \[Pi]/2. By the way, is Rubi some sort of package you add to Mathematica. I ask this as I see you use the command rubiResult = Int[Cos[t] Tan[t]^2, t]; in your Mathematica code.

Answer (score 2):

Nasser:

Comparing plots of the MMA and Rubi integrations with that of the integrand indicates that the Rubi integration is the correct one, no?:

```
Clear[t];
integrand = Cos[t] Tan[t]^2;
mmaResult = Integrate[Cos[t] Tan[t]^2, t];
rubiResult = Int[Cos[t] Tan[t]^2, t];
Grid[{{Plot[mmaResult, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Column[{"Mathematica", mmaResult}], FontSize -> 7]], 
Plot[rubiResult, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Column[{"Rubi", rubiResult}]], 
Plot[integrand, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> Column[{"Integrand", integrand}]]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One should keep in mind that *Mathematica* anti-differentiates functions as functions of complex variables.  Consequently one should expect two indefinite integrals to differ by a complex constant on any connected component of the domain over which the antiderivatives are continuous.  In particular `Log` has a branch cut, and the integral has discontinuities (shown below).

The following shows that the difference between the "standard" antiderivative and *Mathematica*'s is a different constant on different intervals.  *Mathematica* has trouble simplifying, as the OP mentions.  The two `Simplify` examples below show two constants that occur, but the do not work for arbitrary translations of `t`.

```
int1 = (Log@Abs[Sec[t] + Tan[t]] - Sin[t]);
int2 = Integrate[Cos[t] Tan[t]^2, t];

Simplify[int1 - int2, 0 < t < Pi/2]
(*  0  *)

Simplify[int1 - int2 /. t -> t + Pi/2, 0 < t < Pi/2]
(*  I π  *)
```

The result of `Reduce` shows that the difference is a constant, integer multiple of `I Pi`.

```
Reduce[
 difference == int1 - int2 && 0 < t < 4 Pi,
 {difference, t}
 ]
(*
  (difference == 0 &&
     (t == 2 π || 
       2 π < t < 4 π - 4 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] || 
       0 < t < -4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] || 
       4 π + 4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] <= t < 4 π || 
       4 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] <= t < 2 π)) ||
   (difference == -I π &&
     4 π - 4 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]] < t < 4 π + 4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]) ||
   (difference == I π &&
     -4 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]] < t < 4 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]])
*)
```

The plot of the real and imaginary parts of the difference illustrates the periodic discontinuities.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Through[{Re, Im}[int1 - int2]],
 {t, 0, 8 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if I'm missing something but, contrary to what's been said above, it doesn't appear that the  following two expressions are equal:

e1 = -Log[Cos[t/2] - Sin[t/2]] + Log[Cos[t/2] + Sin[t/2]]

e2 = Log[Sec[t] + Tan[t]]

e1 /. t -> Pi

gives: -i Pi

e2 /. t -> Pi

gives: i Pi

e1 /. t -> Pi/2.

gives: 37.0834

e2 /. t -> Pi/2.

gives: 38.025

EDIT:  When t=Pi/2, the arguments of the logs are some very large numbers, so we may be getting round-off errors.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.